# Writing byte "T" on button click to another device through Bluetooth

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

I need to write "T" to an external Bluetooth device when I click btnStart. I have already created a Bluetooth connection and listed the connected device under mBTDevice. I then need to read the incoming bytes and display it on a textView.

I've already researched how to do this using a textfield but want to write the byte just using a button.

Comment: Do you want to send or receive data? You write about "incoming bytes" (sounds like receiving) and about "write the byte" (sounds like sending).

Comment: Are you using Bluetooth Classic of Bluetooth LE?

Comment: @Codo when I've made a sensor module and I've tested using the MIT app inventor. When I send "T" it starts reading my sensors and then sends the information back to me. So both. And it's classic Bluetooth